# too many queueable jobs added to the queue error - make 2nd callout upon receiving response from first callout

Tags: apex, trigger, queueable-interface, asyncapexjob, queueable-apex

i have a triggerHandler class in which on after update i am sending list of records of Account object to queueable class

```
public override void onAfterUpdate() {        
                If( Limits.getQueueableJobs() < Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs() && !Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    System.enqueueJob(new AccountStatusQueueable (lstAccounts));
                }
            }
```

In AccountStatusQueueable class i am making a callout. This api doesn't accepts bulk records, so i have to iterate over the list and
send each record at a time to the api and till the list becomes empty i am enqueueing the same class again.

Now upon receiving positive response from first callout i want to make 2nd callout.
when i am making 2nd callout, **too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2**

What will be the best possible solution to optimize.

```
public class AccountStatusQueueable implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {

public List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
public AccountStatusQueueable(List<Account> accLst) {
this.acc = accLst;

}

public void execute(QueueableContext context) { 

Account objAcc = acc.remove(0);
lstRequestBody.add(new wrapRequestBody(objAcc, createBody(objAcc)));
for(wrapRequestBody objWRB : lstRequestBody) {
    getQuoteResponse = callOutUtility.callOutMethod(objWRB.strBody);
    if(getQuoteResponse.getStatusCode() == 201) {   
        System.enqueueJob(new ContactStatusQueueable (objAcc));
    }
}
if(!acc.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(new AccountStatusQueueable (objAcc));
}

}

}
```

Comment: Can the `lstRequestBody` contain more than one record ever? If yes, then that `for` loop is probably the issue

Comment: It will have only one record

Comment: So, any specific reason to use a `for` loop? Also, can your share the debug log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below approach. Get Map of Account from trigger in AccountStatusQueueable class.

Use for loop for calling API for each record. It will allow 100 call out from single transaction. Once callout limit is reached to 100, create another queue.

You can add all successful processed record in list and then pass all successful accounts to another ContactStatusQueueable class. ContactStatusQueueable  will take list paramter.

```
public class AccountStatusQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public List Map < Id, Account > accsToProcess;
    public List Map < Account > firstQueueSuccessAccounts = new List < Account > ();
    public AccountStatusQueueable(Map < Id, Account > accLst) {
        this.accsToProcess = accLst;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        integer counter = 0;
        boolean flagForNewQueue = false;
        for (ID index: accsToProcess.keySet()) {
            Account objAcc = accsToProcess.get(index);
            if (objAcc != null) {
                try {
                    lstRequestBody.add(new wrapRequestBody(objAcc, createBody(objAcc)));
                    for (wrapRequestBody objWRB: lstRequestBody) {
                        getQuoteResponse = callOutUtility.callOutMethod(objWRB.strBody);
                        if (getQuoteResponse.getStatusCode() == 201) {
                            // On Successful add to list for later process
                            firstQueueSuccessAccounts.add(objAcc);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    system.debug(ex.getMessage());
                }
                counter = counter + 1;

                //remove current element after api call
                accsToProcess.remove(index);
                //Just for creating new queue
                if (counter > 98) {
                    flagForNewQueue = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //call another callout for all successful records
    if (firstQueueSuccessAccounts.size() > 0) {
        System.enqueueJob(new ContactStatusQueueable(firstQueueSuccessAccounts));
    }
    //If callout limit exceed for 1 transaction
    if (flagForNewQueue) {
        System.enqueueJob(new AccountStatusQueueable(accsToProcess));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Dhanik.. if i am sending two different records .. In this line "lstRequestBody.add(new wrapRequestBody(objAcc, createBody(objAcc)));" , i am seeing one reocrd two times..its taking the last record ...

Comment: You can check before adding in list or use Map with Id, and account.

Comment: what i need to check before adding to the list...

Comment: for this " i am seeing one reocrd two times..its taking the last record." . if record is already available in list then don't add.